# Why am I unable to scrape this website?

Tags: python, web-scraping

Say I want to scrape the following url:

https://soundcloud.com/search/sounds?q=edm&filter.created_at=last_week

I have the following python code:

```
import requests
from lxml import html

urlToSearch = 'https://soundcloud.com/search/sounds?q=edm&filter.created_at=last_week'
    page = requests.get(urlToSearch)
    tree = html.fromstring(page.content)
    print(tree.xpath('//*[@id="content"]/div/div/div[3]/div/div/div/ul/div/div/text()'))
```

The trouble is when I print the text at the following xpath:

```
//*[@id="content"]/div/div/div[3]/div/div/div/ul/div/div
```

nothing appears but `[]` despite me confirming that "Found 500+ tracks" should be there. What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that requests does not generate dynamic content.

Right click on the page and view the page source, you'll see that the static content does not include any of the content that you see after the dynamic content has loaded.

However, (using Chrome) open dev tools, click on network and XHR. It looks like you can get the data through an API which is better than scraping anyway!

Comment: Read https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/guide for more information on soundcloud's API.

Comment: sadly soundcloud arent accepting new applications for api access rn

Answer (score 0):

Problem is that with modern websites almost all web pages will change quite a lot after its been loaded with JavaScript, css etc. You will fetch the basic html before any DOM updates etc been made and will look differently to actually visiting the page with a browser.

Use the Selenium WebDriver framework (mostly used for test automation), it will emulate loading the page, executing javascripts etc.

[Selenium Documentation for Python](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/index.html)